# MIPS store words/load words from different offsets of the same address

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm working on a university project in MIPS assembly where I need to manage a telephone catalog by storing words at different offsets in memory (e.g., 0, 20, 40). However, when I try to load and print a word from a specific offset, I consistently get the value stored in the last offset.Any insights into what might be causing this behavior or suggestions on how to troubleshoot would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Get_Entry:
addi $sp,$sp,-4
sw $ra, 0($sp)  
la $a0,Telephone_base_address

jal Get_Entry_Number
move $a0,$v1
jal Get_Entry_Last_Name
move $a0,$v1
jal Get_Entry_First_Name
move $a0,$v1
jal Get_Entry_Phone_Number

li $v0,4

lw $a0,0($v1)
syscall

lw $ra, 0($sp)          ##restore $ra
addi $sp, $sp, 4

jr $ra
    
Get_Entry_Number:
    addi $sp,$sp,-4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)  
    
    move $t0,$a0 
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, get_entry_number
    syscall
    
    li $v0,12
    syscall
    
    li $t1, 60
    
    mul $t2,$t1,$v0
#addition of Telephone base address with the product 
    add $t3,$t0,$t2
    
    move $v1,$t3

    lw $ra, 0($sp)          ##restore $ra
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    
    jr $ra

Get_Entry_Last_Name:
    addi $sp,$sp,-4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)  
    
    move $t0,$a0
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, get_entry_last_name
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 8          # syscall code 8 for read_string
        la $a0,buffer    # address of the buffer
        li $a1, 20        
        syscall
        
        sw $a0,0($t0)
    
    #sll $t0,$t0,20
    
    move $v1,$t0
    
    lw $ra, 0($sp)          ##restore $ra
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    
    jr $ra
    
Get_Entry_First_Name:
    addi $sp,$sp,-4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
            
    move $t0,$a0
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, get_entry_first_name
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 8          # syscall code 8 for read_string
        la $a0,buffer     # address of the buffer
        li $a1, 20        
        syscall
    
    sw $a0,20($t0)
    #sll $a0,$a0,20
    
    move $v1,$t0


    lw $ra, 0($sp)          ##restore $ra
    addi $sp, $sp, 4

    jr $ra
    
Get_Entry_Phone_Number:
    addi $sp,$sp,-4
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
        
    move $t0,$a0
    
    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, get_entry_phone_number
    syscall
    
    li $v0, 8          # syscall code 8 for read_string
        la $a0, buffer      # address of the buffer
        li $a1, 20
        syscall
    
    li $v0, 8          # syscall code 8 for read_string
        move $a0,$t0     # address of the buffer
        li $a1, 20        
        syscall
    
    move $v1,$t0
    
    lw $ra, 0($sp)          ##restore $ra
    addi $sp, $sp, 4
    
    jr $ra
```

Comment: If you are asking about code, it is general practice to post the code (as text, not an image) you are asking about.

Comment: Each of these functions thinks that `$a0` holds `Telephone_base_address` — yet `$a0` is constantly being changed so that you can do some printing using syscall#4.

Comment: Here's what you need to do: debug with simple examples.  Single step each line and verify every line is doing what you're expecting. Before you do this, get to know your data.  MARS, for example, has a list of labels and their values.  So, you can see the value of the string `get_entry_number` for example.  You can compute whether a pointer is referring to an entry in your `Telephone_base_address` as another example.  If you did this you would notice improper values in the registers.

Comment: When there's function calling, verify each and every argument immediately upon entry to any function.  Then upon return, verify that the registers still hold what you expect (very common for the registers to be changed in a way that the function that is resumed/returned-to doesn't work).